# Crystal report formula ELSE IF doesn't work

Tags: crystal-reports

I have following crystal report formula, but it only takes the first `IF` condition and ignores all other `ELSE IF`s. Please help.

```
IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period2} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period2}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period2} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period2}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period2})]
ELSE IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period3} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period3}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period3} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period3}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period3})]
ELSE IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period5} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period5}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period5} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period5}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period5})]
ELSE IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1})]
ELSE IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period6} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period6}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period6} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period6}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period6})]
ELSE IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period7} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period7}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period7} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period7}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period7})]
ELSE IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period8} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period8}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period8} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period8}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period8})]
ELSE IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1}, ";") - 1)] = "1" Then
{CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1})]
```

Comment: your first `IF` is always true for your condition.. check the data that is coming to the formula..

Answer (score 0):

maybe 1st if is always true, so try changing the order of your else if putting the first one as  a last one. You also have below if repeated 2ice

```
    IF {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1}, ";") - 1)] = "1" 
Then {CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1} [(InStr ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1}, " ") + 1) To Length ({CCS_ScheduleMatrixRpt;1.period1})]
```

Comment: Hello Experts...Can someone help with this? i tried suggested option still having the issue. thanks.

Comment: try commenting the first IF to see what happens?

Comment: then nothing gets displayed as they don't match the IF condition. if i have first IF in middle or end it doesn't display anything as that IF doesn't get executed. thanks.

Comment: This means you have some records that meet the first IF condition, and no records that meet any of the other conditions. You'll need to look at the data that is being fed into this statement to see why that is the case and if there is anything more specific that you can separate them by. You might consider using a case statement instead. Some info here: http://www.accoladepublications.com/Crystal-Reports-Tips-and-Tricks/264-case-statements-in-crystal-reports.html there are more examples if you search for "crystal case statement" online.